# setcentercoordinate not allowing to zoom in and out in ios 7

Tags: ios, ios7

The same method is working fine in ios 6
I am using didUpdateToLocation method and its implemented as follows:-

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation     *)Location fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
if(appDelegate->mapView )
{
    if(Span)
    {        
       [appDelegate->mapView  setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(Location.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01f, 0.01f)) animated:YES];

        Span = NO;
    }
    else
    {  
       [appDelegate->mapView  setCenterCoordinate:Location.coordinate animated:YES];
    }
}
```

}

Please suggest what should be done so that the user's location should also be tracked and user should also be able to zoom in and out on the map.The map should also center itself around the current GPS location.

Comment: Every time the user location is updated, it always make the region around the central coordinate of user with certain span provided. Better to set center coordinate in `navigation` button when user wants to see his position.

Answer (score 0):

i use this to zoom the the users location when the map is loaded.

```
- (void)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView {
    NSLog(@"mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap");

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self zoomMapView:mapView ToUserLocation:mapView.userLocation.coordinate];
    }); }


-(void)zoomMapView:(MKMapView*)mapView ToUserLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {

    if (!isZoomed) {
        isZoomed=TRUE;
    MKCoordinateRegion region = mapView.region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;

    region.center = coordinate;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.02;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.02;
    region.span=span;

    [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    } }
```

you can call the `-(void)zoomMapView:(MKMapView*)mapView ToUserLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate` method whenever you want to zoom the the users current location.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. Actually the GPS location is centered around the user's current location. But when i manually try to zoom in and out using pinch in zoom function, the map is not allowing me to zoom and the zoom level still remains the same.

Comment: did you check if the `userInteraction` is enabled for the mapview

Comment: i think the user interaction for map view is enabled by default because the code is working perfectly fine on iOS6